# IOCTL, unix system call uses vairable number of arguments. Is it reliable or safe to use to monitor and control devices?

Tags: c, linux

I have been learning how to control devices in linux based system using IOCTL and reading an article the author said that IOCTL prototype stands out in the list of Unix System call because of the dots  `int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long cmd, ...)` which prevents type checking during compilation. The last part is what I do not get quite well. My concern is, not checking types could create some issues controlling the peripheral? and what would be a more reliable way or best practice to monitor and control a peripheral? Thanks

Comment: it is **I**nput-**O**utput **C**on**T**ro**L**. It is reliable and safe, but it is not type-safe as none of the variadic functions in C are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not checking types means that the function does not prevent you from mistakenly passing a `char` there where your peripheral was expecting an `int`, and well, yes, that could create some issues controlling the peripheral.

So, this means that you need to be careful with the types of the parameters you pass.

The general rule is "GIGO", which stands for "Garbage In Garbage Out".  If you give something garbage, it will give you back garbage.  Type checking is meant to save programmers from really obvious, really dumb errors.  No type checking simply means that the programmers need to be extra careful.

Generally, the first thing you need to do with `ioctl()` is to create a set of functions that fully describe the interface of your peripheral.  Of course these functions will accept properly typed parameters. Then, you will implement each one of those functions by delegating to the type-unsafe `ioctl()` function.  From that moment on, you never directly invoke `ioctl()` again.

Answer (score 3):

> My concern is, not checking types could create some issues controlling the peripheral?

No, at least not directly.  As long as the arguments provided are indeed of the correct number and types, everything will be well (that is, the values will be received correctly by the driver).  The problem is that that compiler cannot help users of your device driver recognize when they are providing the wrong number or types of arguments.

> and what would be a more reliable way or best practice to monitor and control a peripheral?

Alternative ways to monitor and communicate with a peripheral include character and/or block special files (see `mknod()`), setting kernel parameters via `_sysctl()`, and manipulating files presented in the `proc` filesystem via your driver.  Whether any of those are more reliable, more appropriate, or better practice depends on many factors -- exactly what you're trying to do not least among them.

Comment: In many cases a small library that wraps the access to a character device driver (and its un-type-checked or perhaps otherwise fragile  `ioctl()` calls, in Linux) may be best suited. Such a library is especially useful when it also provides bindings to higher-level languages like Python. If well designed, such a library can even hide the low-level implementation details across operating systems, making the library interface portable -- and of course providing type checking et cetera. `libusb` is a widely used example of exactly such a C library.